# PHP stdClass nested properties

Tags: php, stdclass

This used to work for me but it no longer does. What's the new / better methodology for this?

```
$myObj = new stdClass();
$myObj->foo->bar = "content";
$payload = json_encode($myObj);
```

Now I get:

```
Uncaught Error: Attempt to modify property "bar" on null
```

Comment: Was this something that happened after upgrading to PHP8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the nested object explicitly.

```
$myObj = new StdClass;
$myObj->foo = new StdClass;
$myObj->foo->bar = "content";
$payload = json_encode($myObj);
```

But if you're just creating JSON, it would be simpler to use associative arrays instead of objects. They can be written as literals easily.

```
$myArr = ['foo' => ['bar' => "content"]];
$payload = json_encode($myArr);
```